# Necessary to increment PDO variables

Tags: php, pdo

I haven't been able to find anything that explicitly answers this and have been wondering for a while. Sorry if it is a newbie question.

Do I have to increment or change my PDO variables in the following scenario. If I have two queries like so:

```
$stmt     = $dbh->prepare('
    INSERT INTO messages 
        (content) 
    VALUES 
        (:content)
        ');
$stmt->bindValue('content', $content);
$stmt->execute();
$msg_id  = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

.....

```
$stmt1     = $dbh->prepare('
    INSERT INTO something else 
        (stuff) 
    VALUES 
        (:stuff)
        ');
$stmt1->bindValue('stuff', $stuff);
$stmt1->execute();
$var_id  = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

If I used $stmt on both vs. $stmt on the second one is that considered bad practice or once I have $msg_id, can I reuse $stmt? Being new to PDO, it would be convenient to repeat the variables but I don't want to introduce bugs that need to be fixed later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, once you have finished working with $stmt for the first query, you can reuse that PHP variable for another statement/query : nothing prevents your from doing that.

Still, I like the idea of having two variables with **explicit names** -- which means something more informative than `$stmt` and `$stmt1`.

For example, if you have two PHP variables named `$stmtSaveMessage` and `$stmtSaveUser`, each time one of these variables is used, **you will immediately know what the code does** : you will not have to think if `$stmt` right now points to the statement that saves a message, or if it's been overridden to point to the statement that saves something else.

By itself, `$stmt` generally indicates that you are working with a statement, that does something database-related ; but using a more significant variable name will immediately make your code easier to read, easier to understand, and easier to maintain -- and, when programming, we tend to spend more time maintaining old code than writing new one...

Comment: Great, thanks! Between this and Trevesty3's answer I see the full picture which is what I needed. I don't have enough experience to see what problems I may run into on the maintenance end so thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea to reuse the same variable. It is less confusing and saves a little memory.

Really, it is completely up to you, but I personally would consider it to be a bad practice to create a new resource handle for every single query, unless there is a specific reason for hanging onto the old one.